# Is there a way to use tf.exe to set git permissions on multiple repositories in Azure Repos?

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have recently migrated to Azure DevOps from Teamcity, yesterday i migrated around 60 repositories.

I set some permissions on our core project repository using tf.exe and this command

```
tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch 
              /group:[FabrikamProject]\Contributors 
              /collection:https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam-fiber/ 
              /teamproject:FabrikamProject 
              /repository:FabrikamRepo
```

I ideally need to apply the same permissions to the other repositories.

I am wondering if there is a way to use tf.exe to accept wildcards for the repository param such as:

`/repository:*` - this does not work

I really do not want to go through them manually, but will have to otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the wildcard work, but you can iterate the repositories and run the command with a small PowerShell script (using the Rest API):

```
$reposJson = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.0-preview.1 -ContentType application/json

$repos = $reposJson | ConvertFrom-Json

$tfExe = "path/to/exe"

$repos.value.ForEach({

& $txExe git permission /deny:CreateBranch /group:[FabrikamProject]\Contributors /collection:{collection} /teamproject:{project} /repository:$_.name

})
```

You just need to authenticate, you can use `-Credential {email}` (in the `Invoke-RestMethod`) and a window will prompt to put a password or use PAT in this way:

```
$personalAccessToken = "your-personal-access-token-here"
$header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))}
```

And add `-Headers $header` in the `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Comment: I had an issue with this. I had to use `$($_.name)` instead of `$_.name` for the value of `repository` on the call to `tf`. Also, `$tfExe` shouldn't be necessary if done inside a Visual Studio command shell.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `/repository:*` you just remove this parameter to get desired behavior.

The documentation doesn't say so explicitly, but to set project-level permissions (**all existing and new repositories**), you should avoid specifying a particular repository.
I have tried it and it works.

So `tf` code looks like this:

```
tf git permission /deny:CreateBranch 
              /group:[FabrikamProject]\Contributors 
              /collection:https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam-fiber/ 
              /teamproject:FabrikamProject 
              #You should remove this => /repository:FabrikamRepo
```

The documentation shows an example of how to get project-level permission information. Other examples refer to repository level permission settings and the relevant difference is that the `/repository` parameter is specified.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/git-permission-command?view=azure-devops#view-project-level-permissions

Edit: As Edwin Stoteler pointed out in the comments, this only works if you don't set an specific branch. If you specify a branch name then you must specify the repository attribute.

Comment: I tried:

    tf git permission /allow:CreateBranch /group:[Company]\Contributors /collection:https://dev.azure.com/Company/ /teamproject:Company /branch:tweak

And received this error:
**A Git repository must be specified.**

Comment: @edgar_is If you specify /branch, you must also specify /repository. See the documentation.